# How to analyse the systrace report in perfetto

Tags: performance, systrace, perfetto

I have captured a system trace while launching a messaging app and sending message through it. What all things to be analysed in the systrace report for performance evaluation. In the perfetto UI, what are the sections with cpu 0, cpu 1--cpu 7.. are these CPU cores?

Answer (score 0):

The report should help you identify some key performance issues, such as UI jank, high power consumption and startup latency.

For example, few things to look in systrace to analyze the startup time:

1. Competition for monitor-protected resources can introduce significant delay in app startup.
2. Look for unnecessary transactions in your application’s critical path.
3. Concurrent garbage collection is common and has relatively low impact, but if you’re hitting it often consider investigating it(with Android memory profiler)
4. Check for I/O during startup and look for long stalls

Please refer to this links to know more about debugging application performance - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXVxuLvzKek , https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/overview

And sections CPU 0, CPU 1.. are all CPU cores.